# I object to my question being closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

Andrew Barber closed a question regarding GCM servers. My question is at
[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22738566/how-to-implement-a-java-gcm-app-server).

In my opinion the question is not vague.  I have been researching the issue for a couple of weeks.  It's about a gaping hole in the Google GCM docs regarding how to implement  GCM CCS SMPP server code (that is provided).

I am requesting that someone review the question and hopefully open it back up.  I do believe, however, that this issue is moot as apparently no one knows the answer.
Gary

Comment: The latest edit is not conducive to getting the question reopened.  Fix it up.  Remove stuff like this: "Looks like I will have to go elsewhere to discuss this XMPP issue as the preventors of information exchange have closed my thread."

Comment: Sorry for my little rant.  Dealing with some of the people who manage these threads is like dealing with a soviet ministry.  They are so uncompromising that they got my temper up.  Being uncompromising is tolerable if you are also astute but when your are not, it is really hard to take.

Answer (score 14):

That's great. It shows that you didn't bother to read the close reason.

> **Too broad**: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

So, your question:

> I know how to write ASP.Net Web api Rest servers that run under IIS but I don't think there is a Smack library for asp.net so I should probably write the app server part in Java.
>
> So, how can I take this Java code and package it onto a server at my webhoster? Can it run under IIS? Apache?

How is this supposed to be answerable in a few paragraphs? It sounds like you don't know what you're doing and need a long tutorial.

Answer (score -8):

Now that I have researched the issue by finding some very good information sources, I know the answer to my "broad" question.  The following is the correct (or at least very good) answer to my posted question . . .

"The example code in the docs will run under Apache Tomcat pretty much as is. It could also run as a standard Java EE Web app with Servlets and JSPs. There is also an XMPP .NET library from AG Software called agsXMPP if you prefer to go that way.

The real problem is that the CCS XMPP part of Google Cloud Messaging is pretty embryonic at this stage and that is likely the reason for no hard examples in the docs.  In the real world the CcsClient needs to be much more robust because it has to cope with connection loss so, at this point, you need to develop you own persistence solution.

You might want to consider going with the HTTP side of GCM for server to client traffic and have your phone apps post directly to your own server for client to server traffic."

So, I submit this as data that tends to show that (a) the question was not too broad and (b) that it was comletely answerable.

S.O. has been a valuable tool through my year long ramp up on Android but in my opinion you guys are too hard-nosed and sometimes actually prevent information exchange.  You certainly prevented me getting the answer above a week or so ago.  I've seen you do worse to many others.

Comment: That a question is answerable is in no way proof that the question is not too broad. Indeed, one of the reasons to close a question as too broad is that it is framed in such a way that a multitude of equally good answers could answer it.

Comment: @DeanBlakely You apparently fail to see the point. Questions should be worded in a way that **someone else** could conceivably answer in a concise manner. Complaining about the community being "hard-nosed" isn't going to help a "too broad" question be more specific. Also comments like "apparently no one knows the answer" aren't going to make you any friends here; it will put most people off entirely.